# Vfork() and more corruption

Tags: c, unix, bsd

my question is on execution what will happen to parent stack?

```
main()
{
    f();
    g();
}
f()
{
   vfork();
}
g()
{ 
    int blast[100],i;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        blast[i]=i;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is undefined as per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vfork.html

> the behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() [...] returns from the function in which vfork() was called [...]

Comment: but what can be the probable output?

Comment: *Anything* can happen. In common implementations, the child will write zeros to the stack space of the parent and later the parent will try to return from a function with a completely clobbered stack frame.

Answer (score -2):

In practice, `vfork` is not very useful any more. Read its [vfork man](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vfork) page for Linux, which says that *POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of vfork().* the behavior is practically nearly the same as for `fork` (except that the parent is suspended). So I'll bet that practically, `vfork` is nearly like `fork` today. But all the programs I've read in the last ten years used `fork` not `vfork` (because the lazy copy on write paging behavior is efficient enough today).

Comment: Actually, modern use of `vfork()` is more similar to `posix_spawn`, i.e. you cannot `fork()` (efficiently anyway) without a MMU.

Comment: The reasons for using vfork nowadays are mostly the same. While copying page tables is faster than copying the memory, it still takes considerable time, especially for large processes.